# How can I select the largest value in one column, and then the largest value in the other column?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table looking like this:

```
ID  quote_no  version
------------------------
1   123       1
2   123       2
3   123       1
4   123       2
5   321       1
6   321       1
```

I would like to select the latest version of each quote, and if theres multiple records of that version i would like to get the row with the highest ID.

(in this case the query should produce the following result):

```
ID  quote_no  version
------------------------
4   123       2
6   321       1
```

How could I do that in a query?

Answer (score 2):

You can approach this with a `not exists` clause:

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.quote_no = t.quote_no and
                        (t2.version > t.version or
                         t2.version = t.version and t2.id > t.id
                        )
                 );
```

If you just want the one with the highest `id` (which is also consistent with your results), you can do:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select quote_no, max(id) as maxid
      from table t
      group by quote_no
     ) tt
     on t.id = tt.maxid;
```

Comment: I don't think they want just the highest `id`. By coincidence it works in this case, but they want the highest id, for the highest version number. At least, that's how I read it.

Comment: @McAdam331 . . . I just added that in, in case it happens to work for the OP and s/he overcomplicated the question.

Comment: Is there are reason for the downvote or is this just malicous downvoting on all the answers to this question?

Comment: Probably just someone in a bad mood. I can't think for any reason why this should be downvoted. Especially after you clarified the second part in the comments.

Comment: @McAdam331 . . . It looks like malicious downvoting, because Golez's answer was also downvoted (and it is now correct after the edits).

Answer (score 2):

I would write a subquery that gets the largest version for each `quote_no`, like this:

```
SELECT quote_no, MAX(version) AS maxVersion
FROM myTable
GROUP BY quote_no;
```

And you can join that with your original table, and use another `MAX()` function to get the largest id:

```
SELECT MAX(m.id), m.quote_no, mt.maxVersion
FROM myTable m
JOIN(
  SELECT quote_no, MAX(version) AS maxVersion
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY quote_no) mt ON mt.quote_no = m.quote_no AND mt.maxVersion = m.version
GROUP BY m.quote_no;
```

Works fine in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1823c6/2).

Answer (score 1):

The latest X records per group is a tough problem in MySQL, except when X is 1 as in your case. You can do it like this. For each quote, join all rows that have the same quote_no, but a greater version., or the same version but with a larger ID. Then you can apply a filter to only keep those rows that don't have a greater version:

```
SELECT
  t1.*
FROM  
  YourTable t1
  LEFT JOIN YourTable t2 ON
       t2.quote_no = t1.quote_no AND -- Quote must match anyway
       ( t2.version > t1.version OR -- Version must be larger
         ( t2.version = t1.version AND -- Or if version is the same... 
           t2.ID > t1.ID )      -- ID must be larger.
WHERE
  t2.quote_no IS NULL
```

Comment: Using MAX function and GROUP BY clause is more simple.

Comment: Hmm.. Yes. If you need just the quote no and the version, then yes, but if you want to have the right `ID` of that row, than MAX is not guaranteed to give you the right ID as well.

Comment: It's dangerous to rely on that, and the example data seems to disagree. Row 3 has the same quote_no, but a lower version than Row 2.

Comment: Yes I didn't see that version could be downgrade (row ID = 3).

Comment: (+1) Correct answers don't deserve downvotes.  I think the downvoting was just a malicious endeavor.

Answer (score -2):

Try something like that :

```
SELECT t2.* 
FROM QuoteTable t2
JOIN (SELECT 
              MAX(ID) AS t1.LatestId,
              quote_no
              FROM QuoteTable t1
              GROUP BY quote_no)
ON t2.id = t1.LatestId;
```

EDIT : the Parent SELECT statement prevents version number error.

Comment: This will only work if the IDs are in the same order as the version numbers. If that was the case, then `version` would probably be obsolete. For instance, if record with ID 4 didn't exist, then `MAX(ID)` would return `3` and `MAX(version)` would still return `2`, even though version 2 applies to record 2, not 3. Ergo: This might (and will sooner or later) give you the wrong ID.

Comment: Your modified query is still wrong and returns just the highest ID, not taking the version into account at all.